# exporting a default async function is not defined in current file

Tags: javascript, babeljs

The following works perfectly:

```
export default function x () {
  return 'hello world'
}

export function y () {
  return x()
}

console.log(y())
```

However this does not work:

```
export default async function x () {
  return 'hello world'
}

export function y () {
  return x()
    .then(console.log)
}

y()
```

When the `default` function is `async` for some reason `x is not defined`.

Comment: Do you need a polyfill of some kind for this? I remember some kind of babel polyfill solving something like this. Also what happens if you remove "default".

Comment: @TimConsolazio If I remove it, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm using the babel `latest` plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue inside babel project: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/3786